# How to most efficiently parse a web page using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to parse a simple web page and get data from html, such as "src", "data-attr", etc. How can I do this most efficiently using Node.js? If it helps, I'm using Node.js 0.8.x.

P.S. This is the [site](http://tunes.io/) I'm parsing. I want to get a list of current tracks and make my own html5 app for listen on mobile devices.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I have done this a lot. You'll want to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) if the website that you're scraping is heavily using JavaScript. Note that PhantomJS is not Node.js. It's a completely different JavaScript runtime. You can integrate through [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) or [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom), but they are both kinda hacky. YMMV with those. Avoid anything to do with jsdom. It'll cause you headaches - this includes [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/).

What you should use is [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) in conjunction with [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). This will be sufficient for most web pages.

I wrote a blog post on using Cheerio with Request: [Quick and Dirty Screen Scraping with Node.js](http://procbits.com/2012/04/11/quick-and-dirty-screen-scraping-with-node-js-using-request-and-cheerio/) But, again, if it's JavaScript intensive, use PhantomJS in conjunction with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

Hope this helps.

Snippet using Request and Cheerio:

```
var request = require('request')
  , cheerio = require('cheerio');

var searchTerm = 'screen+scraping';
var url = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + searchTerm;

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  links = $('.sb_tlst h3 a'); //use your CSS selector here
  $(links).each(function(i, link){
    console.log($(link).text() + ':\n  ' + $(link).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Comment: I have a question for you, Richardson I really hope PhantomJS can achieve this I'm thinking about, so is it possible to Interact with non-same domain site, Like login and post some thread (even on fórum, for example). I'd like to see something like this (C# sample): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000185/how-to-interact-with-a-website-without-a-browser

Comment: @jp-richardson is this answer still valid?

Comment: @UladzimirHavenchyk yes, these are still my preferred methods.

Comment: What about using cheerio with phantomjs+casperjs? Then you get a faster jquery (because all you need is to scrape, not mutate the dom) and browser-side javascript! Or would it be better to just embed jquery all the time?

Answer (score 4):

You could try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Here's the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#DOM_Manipulation) for using it for screen scraping.

Comment: Is it fast? I think that web-kit load system too heavy.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't used it myself, sorry.

Comment: PhantomJS is slow, relatively speaking that is.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @JP Richardson that Cheerio is best for scraping non-JS-heavy sites.
For JS-heavy sites, use [Casper](http://casperjs.org/). It provides great abstractions over Phantom and a promises-style API. They go over how to scrape in their docs: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for phantom, use node-phantom. I have a git hub repository using them together to generate pdf files from html if you want to have a look.
But i wouldn't go for phantom because it does more than what you usually want and cheerio is faster.